# Setting A Panel texture in GDScript

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot-4

I am messing around with Godot, and I couldn't seem to find a way to set the texture of a `Panel` node in Godot. First I tried using the `get_theme_stylebox()` function, but I don't know how that works.
I read the Godot documentation and didn't find anything there. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an `StyleBoxTexture` to the `Panel` either by:

- Defining it in a `Theme` which you set in the `theme` property
- Or by setting it in the `theme_override_styles/panel` property.

If this texture is intended for all (or at least most) panels, use a `Theme`. As you can set the `Theme` in the root `Control` and all children `Control` take it.

---

Alternatively, you can set a `ShaderMaterial` in the `material` property, and write a shader that lets you set a texture. For example:

```
shader_type canvas_item;

uniform sampler2D tex:source_color;

void fragment() {
    COLOR = texture(tex, UV);
}
```

Using a `ShaderMaterial` would give you more control over how the texture is used, but you need to write the shader code for that.

---

Also consider using a `TextureRect` instead of a `Panel`.

Comment: Thanks you. I may use a TextureRect instead, since there's no real reason for the Panel, but I will keep this in mind when I do use Panels! Thanks, this helped a lot.